# Will any PS3 Dualshock 3 work on any Bluetooth capable PC?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, game-controller

I am searching for the convenience of a cheap Dualshock 3, and I've found really cheap ones online that say they are wireless; have a built-in, rechargeable battery; and function using Bluetooth.

Having a Bluetooth PC with Windows, I was wondering if ***`any`*** wireless, PS3-compatible DS3 will work on a Bluetooth capable Windows x86-64 PC with all working, applicable hardware and drivers.

I ask because some are second-hand manufactured, non-Sony models that mimic the DS3s and are much cheaper to make and sell. But if they work on the PS3 with Bluetooth, should I assume they will also work on a PC with Bluetooth and the right drivers too? That's all I'm really wondering, generally.

I don't want to regret buying a controller that, for some reason, cannot work on Windows/platforms, and I don't want to spend much money either, so it's a hard draw and I'm trying for the best deal.

I also ask because some second-hand sellers of wireless, Bluetooth Dualshock 3s claim that their controllers **do not work on PCs**, despite the fact that Dualshock 3s should, in general, work.

Is there any way I can be more confident in the buy? Anything else I should know before picking?

Answer (score 0):

There are no official Bluetooth drivers to connect a Dual Shock 3 to a PC, all drivers are provided by 3rd party sources.

As with any 3rd party drivers there can be issues when trying to use it, most likely the second hand sellers do not want to deal with having do perform technical support for people trying to use the 3rd party drivers so they just say it does not work.

In theory any controller that can successfully communicate wirelessly with a PS3 should be useable on a PC using the same 3rd party driver software as you use with the Sony controllers.

Comment: Adding this as a comment because it really is a opinionated comment. Just go with a wired Xbox 360 controller instead, they have official support for windows, just plug it in and it is recognized. Also many games have direct 360 controller support, almost no games will have PS3 controller support (In fact most 3rd party drivers try to trick games by making your PS3 controller look like a 360 controller to make it work)

Comment: It's not a bad option, but I don't really like the design of Xbox controllers, and I don't want it to be wired because it's always a hassle with it being in the way. To add more, the Xbox 360 controllers are much more expensive than I was willing to pay (which was around ten dollars). I realize there are no official drivers, but if people can get their Dualshock 3s to work so easily, should I be trusting to buy just any?

Comment: Yes, yes? Yes...

Comment: I don't know. I guess so, try it out and if you are wrong its only $10.